Using verbs like 'project' without an indirect object?
I am doing line and copyediting on a research grant proposal, and I discovered a curious use of the verb 'project' that had no indirect object. The sentence is like this: "I will project deaths due to gun violence." The writer wants to develop a model that can be used to predict a variable of interest (in my toy example, gun-related deaths) in the future under a range of possible scenarios.
This looks wrong to me, like the verb is lacking an indirect object. My brain wants something like "I will project deaths due to gun violence over the next decade."
So I'm curious about 'to project' in particular, but I also find the more general question interesting: are there transitive verbs in English that require an indirect object? If so, are there general rules that distinguish them from verbs that may take an indirect object?

I don't see why the prepositional phrase is required. The fact that you're projecting over some time frame is implicit, you don't need to state the actual period (it's likely they won't know how far in the future they can project until they do the research)

Maybe "predict" would be a better word.

But 'over the next decade' is not an indirect object: it is a temporal adjunct (arguably near-obligatory) 'He sidled' similarly really needs a (directional) PP such as 'along the street'. And note that 'predict' also sounds better with such an addition, or with a fuller statement ('I  predict that there will be deaths due to gun violence'). // As Barmar hints, 'project' seems a dubious choice here.

Thanks for the info! Yes, not an indirect-object issue after all, thanks for the clarification. Yes, 'project' is weird, but it feels jargony so I don't want to lecture him too much. Will suggest 'predict'...

I understand, "predict" sounds too Nostradamusy.

Neither of those sentences has an indirect object; an indirect object would be something like *"I projected him the earnings."

I think jargon is the point; you can't just change a verb, sometimes. Is it what they do for a living (hard math) or do they have a Palantír or something?
